Offer users a large file to download from Webserver? (4 - 20 GB)
First I would like to apologize for my stupidity...
I need to provide a download of large videofiles from a webpage.
The files are between 4 and 20 gb.
Question: What is the right way to enable such a download?
I tried some ways but the download always aborted or did not work
First try was this because I have used it for some smaller files in the past - but in this case the download stopped at 1 GB
header("Content-Type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
readfile($dir.$file);

I tried also to download it chunk by chunk. The browser started the download correctly but crashed after a short time.
$chunksize = 5 * (1024 * 1024); //5 MB (= 5 242 880 bytes) per one chunk of file.

    if(file_exists($filename))
    {
        set_time_limit(10800);

        $size = intval(sprintf("%u", filesize($filename)));

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($filename).'"');

        if($size > $chunksize)
        {
            $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

            while (!feof($handle))
            {
                print(@fread($handle, $chunksize));

                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
        else readfile($filename);

        exit;
    }
    else echo 'File "'.$filename.'" does not exist!';*/

Last try was X-Sendfile, but I think the webhosting Server does not support it, because it does not work?
if (file_exists($fileonserver))
    {
        // send the right headers
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Content-type: ' . $type);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileonserver));

        header('X-Sendfile: ' . $fileonserver);
        //exit;
    }
    else
    {
        die('File loading failed.');
    }


Is there a reason you need to do this in PHP, and you can’t instead rely directly on the server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.)? Authentication, tracking, etc? Just asking because the server might be better optimized for this, especially retrying the download if it stops for whatever reason

"but in this case the download stopped at 1 GB", then check the logs on the server to figure out why it stopped. Also check the notes in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

@ChrisHaas The user should select the preferred file in a form, transmit, and then the download should start. The rest doesn't matter.
But I only have access to the server via FTP and I can take some basic config on the webserver, because its only a webhosting server.

@user24772931, what I'm wondering is if you can redirect to the file afterwards, instead of using fread, print, set_time_limit, readfile, etc. There are totally valid reasons to use PHP, I get it, but if they don't apply I'm just seeing if we can simplify. Or, if they do apply, can you try something different. For instance, you could create a symbolic link that you redirect to, and have cron delete expired items after a certain amount of time.

@shingo Log says: [Apache] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function and [nginx] 17927#0: *74420752 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream
